# Why is a part of my string omitted?

Tags: javascript, string, angular

I have a method in my Angular service that combines a series of strings into an url used for a get request for Google's Youtube Data API v3.

When I finally combine the strings, a part of it is omitted (see the ... in the log below).

Each value is logged, as well as how the result is when combined with classic concatenation and string interpolation. Both omit a part of my string, breaking my get request.

Why do this happen? How can I prevent this?

**LOG**

```
Parts
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/ search AIzjSyCA_g_zkSTs43Py7yjZtOAcXWvkwQTdU snippet zelda 3 items(id,snippet(title,description))

Concat Combined
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzjSyCA_g_zkSTs43Py7yjZtO…art=snippet?q=zelda?maxResults=3?fields=items(id,snippet(title,description))

Interpolation Combined
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key=AIzjSyCA_g_zkSTs43Py7yjZtO…art=snippet&q=zelda&maxResults=3&fields=items(id,snippet(title,description))
```

**METHOD**

```ts
public searchByKeyword(): Observable<any> {
    const base = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/';
    const endpoint = 'search';
    const apiKey = 'AIzjSyCA_g_zkSTs43Py7yjZtOAcXWvkwQTdU';
    const part = 'snippet';
    const query = 'zelda';
    const maxResults = '3';
    const fields = 'items(id,snippet(title,description))';

    console.log('Parts');
    console.log(base, endpoint, apiKey, part, query, maxResults, fields);

    const concatCombined = base + endpoint + '?key=' + apiKey + '?part=' + part + '?q=' + query + '?maxResults=' + maxResults + '?fields=' + fields;

    console.log('Concat Combined');
    console.log(concatCombined);

    const interpolationCombined = `${base}${endpoint}?key=${apiKey}?part=${part}&q=${query}&maxResults=${maxResults}&fields=${fields}`;

    console.log('Interpolation Combined');
    console.log(interpolationCombined);

    return this.http.get(interpolationCombined, this.getHeaderOption()).map(x => x.json());
}
```

Note the API key was modified for security reasons. It does not work.

### UPDATE

It seems the error is browser related. Edge does not shorten my url, but instead cannot read the final two )) of my field section part.

I guess this changes the question to how I can encode/combine my url in a way that browsers can actually combine it and understand the whole part.

Comment: Why exposing your API key to the world?

Comment: @haim770 now read the last line again

Comment: @Jamiec, Sorry. I was too quick to judge.

Comment: I just plugged this into a codepen and I'm not experiencing the same thing -- could it just be a line character limit in your console?


   /// edit: Well, no, you said it's breaking your request. I guess I'm wondering if the truncated logging is a red herring. Try making a [requestbin](https://requestb.in/) and sending your data there. Sometimes it's useful to see what's being _received_, rather than what's (purportedly) being _sent_.

Comment: @shabs Hmmm... I just tested this in Edge, and here my url isn't cut short. Instead Edge can't read the final two )) of the fields part... So it seems the problem is browser related.  Will update post

Comment: :) good luck, happy troubleshooting! sometimes the key is just to get past our initial assumptions, hehe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using too many question marks ("?") in the query URL. You only need the first one to define the query parameters, then use ampersand mark ("&") to limit each parameter.

```
const concatCombined = base + endpoint + '?key=' + apiKey + '&part=' + part + '&q=' + query + '&maxResults=' + maxResults + '&fields=' + fields;
const interpolationCombined = `${base}${endpoint}?key=${apiKey}&part=${part}&q=${query}&maxResults=${maxResults}&fields=${fields}`;
```

Comment: Ahahaha, Oh how I can only laugh at myself. I knew I could use only one question mark, but I guess I added one by accident with all my copy pasting. You're a lifesaver :)